# how to declare volatile iterator in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, volatile

Is there a way to declare an iterator which is a member variable in a class and that can be incremented using a member function even though the object of that class is const.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be with the "mutable" keyword.

```
class X
{
public:
   bool GetFlag() const
   {
      m_accessCount++;
      return m_flag;
   }
private:
   bool m_flag;
   mutable int m_accessCount;
};
```

Comment: This will work for integers but if it is an iterator to a list or a map it doesnt work on const objects. It throws error at iter = list.begin() saying no "=" operator available.

Comment: @tmpforspam: Without being able to see the complete error message you're getting, it sounds like "list" is also const and you should be using a const_iterator.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you need iterator as a member? Iterators have an ability: they become invalid. It is a small sign of a design problem.

Comment: I want to iterate through a list using a member functions. getFirst and getNext kind of....But for that I want to declare a mutable iterator so taht I can iterate on const objects.

Comment: go for the STL-Design of iterators. It is accepted in the C++ comunity and would not suprise other developers. That would mean that the iterator is not part of the class.

Comment: @tmpforspam: if the behavior of your object changes when calling your member function, it's not a const function.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it mutable, not volatile.

Answer (score -1):

Got it.

```
using namespace std;
class tmptest
{
    public:
    void getNextItr()const
    {
        m_listItr = m_list.begin();
        m_listItr++;
    }
    list<string> m_list;
    mutable list<string>::const_iterator m_listItr;
};
```

Mutable along with `const_iterator` works. Thanks for reminding me mutable versus volatile.
I got volatile confused with mutable. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a serious breach-of-contract: after calling the `getNextItr()` function, client code will assume the object is still the same, but it's not.